# Unable to make a domain redirection in Django from example.com to www.example.com

Tags: django, redirect, proxy, dns

I get the following message when I browse to `example.com`

```
500 - Internal Server Error
```

I get my 404 error message when I browse to `www.example.com` which indicates my site is alive.

**How can you make a domain redirection without .htaccess by Django from example.com to www.example.com?**

**My urls.py**

```
     from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

     from django.contrib import admin
     admin.autodiscover()

     urlpatterns = patterns('',
     # Example:
     # (r'^{{ project_name }}/', include('{{ project_name }}.foo.urls')),

     (r'^home/', include('index.html')),

     # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
     # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
     (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

     (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
     )
```

**[edit]**

I have the following answer from Djangohosting:

> Remove the website proxy for [example.com] and add [example.com] in the aliases section of the [www.example.com] website.

I am not completely sure what it means.

1. How can you remove the website proxy for `example.com`?
2. Where can you find the aliases section of the website `www.example.com`?

Comment: Why can't you use .htaccess (or whatever other mechanism is provided by the web server you might be using)?

Comment: @mipadi: I can but I do not want to. I want to learn to configure my site without .htaccess. One told me that .htaccess, which is full of configurations, is a sign of bad security in Apache.

Comment: Generally speaking, Django doesn't deal with server configurations -- at least not in this situation. A Django app is served from a server. So if you want to automatically redirect from site.com to www.site.com, an Apache configuration file of some sort is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it solves all your problems but if you want to do it via django, try a middleware

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class WWWRedirectMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.META['HTTP_HOST'].startswith('www.'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.example.com')
```

Remember that it must be executed before any other middleware.

Based on [this one](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/434/), didn't test it.

Answer (score 3):

Checking out [PREPEND_WWW](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#prepend-www) setting might help.

Comment: The problem is that you wouldn't be able to find the site for the prepend_www setting to work.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The 500 Internal Server error is likely caused by this line:

```
(r'^home/', include('index.html')),
```

The `include()` function is a way to include other URL config files, not static HTML files. You'd have to either serve `index.html` as a [static file](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#howto-static-files) at the given URL (/home), or write a view that simply renders the file.

Comment: I commented the line out. The same error occurs. @mipadi: Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

> I get the following message when I browse to `example.com`
>
> 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> I get my 404 error message when I browse to `www.example.com` which indicates my site is alive.

It is likely the other way around.  The 500 message means that your site is active, but giving an error.  What you have to understand is that the `example.com`/`www.example.com` part of the url serves to find *which server* to connect to.  By the time your Django application gets called, this part has already been completed, so there os no way to do this from Django.

Instead, you want to set up `www` as a subdomain of `example.com` and make them point the same place.  See the first example here:  [virtualhosts examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/examples.html)

**UPDATE**  I just noticed that you stated that *your* 404 was showing up, so ignore the first two sentences.  Either way, the solution would likely be the same.  :-)